# The @order is invalid when defining the filter

Tags: spring-boot, filter

In springboot2, I defined a series of filters and then annotated them with @order annotations; but I found a problem. When I started with springboot, everything was fine, but once I deployed the project to tomcat At the time, I found that their execution order was not executed in the order of @order;

Comment: Now with Spring Boot 2 you can use *@DependsOn* instead of *@Order*

Comment: @DependsOn is only used to determine the dependencies between beans, not the order in which filters are specified.

Comment: *@Order* defines the sort order for annotated components, not for configuration classes.

Comment: When deploying Spring Boot isn't in control of the `Filter` instances but your container is. As that doesn't know anything about an `@Order` those will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by registering the filter with FilterRegistrationBean, but I haven't thought of a better way. Unless defined by the name of the filter